# Ngx Bootstrap modal - do something after hide modal

Tags: angular, typescript, modal-dialog, ngx-bootstrap

I have modal, and inside that I have a login button:

```
<button type="button" (click)="save()" class="btn btn-primary">
      login
</button>
```

If I click it, I would like to first: hide modal, second: navigate to another route.

When I do something like below:

```
save() {
     this.modal.hide();
     this.router.navigate(['login'])
}
```

I can see that first page is navigated, then modal is hidden.

I would like to navigated when hide action is finished.

How can I do something like that? I don't want to use timeout or something like this.

Comment: https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals#service-events

Answer (score 2):

Use the onHidden() function

```
save() {
     this.modal.hide();
     this.modal.onHidden.subscribe(() => {
         this.router.navigate(['login']) 
     });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to use onHidden property

```
save() {
    this.modal.hide();
    this.modal.onHidden.subscribe(() => {
      this.router.navigate(["login"]);
    });
  }
```